# npx react-native error (create react-native app error)

Tags: react-native

I want to create a new React Native app, so I executed the following command on my Mac:

`$npx react-native@latest init myApp`

Then, I encountered the following error.

`npm ERR! code EEXIST npm ERR! syscall rename npm ERR! path /Users/curruser/.npm/_cacache/tmp/e2cf48ca npm ERR! dest /Users/curruser/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/ba/7d/330ffeaac49f92d1eb7b5b1788dc7e5749ef654c1051edb3870875e4291ea5b86e66c030e5233550d15e5c642ba84e011d71dc334e085891359fb9b8be9c npm ERR! errno -13 npm ERR! EACCES: permission denied, rename '/Users/curruser/.npm/_cacache/tmp/e2cf48ca' -> '/Users/curruser/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/ba/7d/330ffeaac49f92d1eb7b5b1788dc7e5749ef654c1051edb3870875e4291ea5b86e66c030e5233550d15e5c642ba84e011d71dc334e085891359fb9b8be9c' npm ERR! File exists: /Users/curruser/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/ba/7d/330ffeaac49f92d1eb7b5b1788dc7e5749ef654c1051edb3870875e4291ea5b86e66c030e5233550d15e5c642ba84e011d71dc334e085891359fb9b8be9c npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.`

I initially thought it was a permission issue, so I executed the following command:

`$chmod -R u+rwx /Users/curruser/.npm`

After running the command, I still encountered the same error. Can anybody help me? Any information, no matter how small, would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know.

Thank you.